# Receiving a org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm attempting to build an application level view with Spring JPA.  I'm also using lombok.

There is an existing client already using this web service which can't be changed at this time.
We have a new client which needs the same data and even more now.  So I thought this could
be addressed with an application level view so to speak.

The basic scope of the problem is I have 3 entities: A, B and C.

A and C are entities pointed at the same table.  C has more properties than A.
Both C and A have references to B.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Foo", schema="dbz")
public class A {
  @Id
  @Column(name="FOO_I")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="FOO_I",nullable=false)
  private Set<B> items = new HashSet<B>();

  @Column(name="X")
  private String x;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Bar", schema="dbz")
public class B {
  @Id
  @Column(name="BAR_I")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(name="Y")
  private String y;

  @Column(name="Z")
  private int z;
}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Foo", schema="dbz")
public class C {
  @Id
  @Column(name="FOO_I")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="FOO_I",nullable=false)
  private Set<B> items = new HashSet<B>();

  @Column(name="X")
  private String x;

  @Column(name="MoreData")
  private String moreData;

  //And much more other data...
}
```

When I comment out the @Entity and @Table on class C and rebuild, I don't get an exception in my validation tests.

When I leave the @Entity and @Table annotations on class C, I get the following exception:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of _items_FOO_IBackref found in com.acme.Bar

If I rename items to bars in C, then I get the following exception:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.acme.Bar column: FOO_I (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Is there any way to get hibernate to accept 2 java classes backed by the same table which relate to another entity?  I'm not sure if I am missing something here or if this is a framework limitation.

Comment: The annotations are telling JPA to create two columns with the same name `FOO_I` in table `B`. Thats why you are getting the error `Repeated column in mapping for entity`, one of the fields should be marked as read only,  with `@JoinColumn(.... insertable="false", updatable="false")`.

Comment: @rubenlop88 I renamed one of the properties and received a different exception.  What if I need that association to be writeable in both classes?  Would inheritance perhaps work instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are using **component mapping** so use **@Embedded** annotation for the **A** class without using @Entity, @Id and @Table annotations here is a useful link;

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-component-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: I would want to have a CRUDRepository<A> which returns instances of A by Id and a CRUDRepository<C> which returns instances of C by Id.  I could see having A as a component of C (since A is smaller and a subset of C) but I don't know if I could still do a Repository against A then?